# sed grep to group values on multi lines

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a file that can resembles to something like that:

```
function(a, b, c1, d1, e1, f1);
function(a, b, c2
    ,d2, e2
   f2);
useless things
function(a, b, c3,
         /* something lol */
         // something else */
         d3, e3
         , f3
);
```

The idea is to get something like:

```
c1
d1
e1
f1
c2
d2
e2
f2
c3
d3
e3
f3
```

I am using sed to remove things that are useless between each function, so I came with

```
sed -n '/function(/,/);/p' file
```

Here I get the three functions without the `useless things`.

Now I am tring to put the thing between function into one line maybe delete also the things after `//` or between `/* */`. But I don't know how can I "concat" things so I can get 3 lines instead of 10

Comment: @AntoineMorrier, _I don't know how can [...] I can get 3 lines instead of 10_? Is the 12 row text file your desired output or not? Be clear.

Comment: This command reproduces your desired output: `sed -zE 's/[cdef][0-9]/\n&/g;s/(^|\n)([^cdef]|.[^1-3])[^\n]*//g;s/([1-3])[^\n]*/\1/g;s/^\n//g'`.

Comment: `a, b,` not required in output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grep

`grep -o '[a-z][0-9]' < input_File`

Demo :

```
$cat file.txt 
function(a, b, c1, d1, e1, f1);
function(a, b, c2
    ,d2, e2
   f2);
useless things
function(a, b, c3,
         /* something lol */
         // something else */
         d3, e3
         , f3
);
$grep -o '[a-z][0-9]' < file.txt 
c1
d1
e1
f1
c2
d2
e2
f2
c3
d3
e3
f3
$
```